# How to pack properties file in jar using maven

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I have been trying to pack the properties file inside my jar using Maven but no luck so far.

Project Structure:

```
src/main/java
    All java source files
src/test/java
    All test java source files
src/main/resource
    All properties files. For example, application.properties
...
pom.xml
```

POM.XML File Contents:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Database</groupId>
    <artifactId>Executor</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>DatabaseExecutor</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.framework.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <spring.framework.group.id>org.springframework</spring.framework.group.id>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <fully.qualified.main.class>com.applications.App</fully.qualified.main.class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.framework.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.framework.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.framework.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.framework.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${spring.framework.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>${fully.qualified.main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have created a `build.bat` file to build the code having the below content.

```
@ECHO OFF
call mvn -e pre-clean
call mvn -e clean
call mvn -e compile
call mvn -e package -DskipTests
```

Command Prompt Logs:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< Database:Executor >--------------------------
[INFO] Building DatabaseExecutor 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.146 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-02T19:10:26+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< Database:Executor >--------------------------
[INFO] Building DatabaseExecutor 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.465 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-02T19:10:28+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< Database:Executor >--------------------------
[INFO] Building DatabaseExecutor 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.165 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-02T19:10:33+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< Database:Executor >--------------------------
[INFO] Building DatabaseExecutor 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Copying log4j-api-2.14.0.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\log4j-api-2.14.0.jar
[INFO] Copying log4j-core-2.14.0.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\log4j-core-2.14.0.jar
[INFO] Copying junit-3.8.1.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\junit-3.8.1.jar
[INFO] Copying spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Copying spring-jcl-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\spring-jcl-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Copying spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Copying spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Copying spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Copying spring-expression-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\spring-expression-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Copying ojdbc14-12.2.0.1.jar to C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\libs\ojdbc14-12.2.0.1.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ Executor ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\target\Executor-0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.292 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-02T19:10:39+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Though the executable jar file is getting created successfully but the properties file is missing in the jar file. I'm not sure what is the mistake here. Can somebody please point out the mistake or tell me if I missed something.

Thanks In Advance,

Varun Jain

Comment: Should work out of the box

Comment: No need to configure resources with includes. By default all files in `src/main/resources` will be packaged into the resulting jar file... furthermore to get an executable jar you should take a look at maven-assembly-plugin instead using dependency plugin to copy and jar plugin etc...  Apart from that if you have an `appllication.properties` it looks like a spring boot application which should be packaged via spring-boot-maven-plugin etc. ...

Comment: This part is interesting: `[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\VarunJain\Documents\Personal\DevEnv\_Setups\PracticeWorkspace\DatabaseExecutor\src\main\resources` ... ?

Comment: @Antoniossss: That is what my understanding was prior to having the problem. But it is not packing the properties inside the jar.

Comment: @khmarbaise: You noticed a good point that it is skipping the "resourceDirectory ". My application is not a spring boot app but I added all the dependencies though I forgot to remove the unnecessary ones'. The problem with "maven-assembly-plugin" is that the jar is not executable, i.e. "main-class" attribute of MANIFEST.MF is missing altogether.

Comment: If you use maven-assembly-plugin than you have wrongly configured it....